# Use variable inside Alertmanager Promql query

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I have some some metrics like this:

```
restarts{service="foo-1"}
restarts{service="foo-2"}
restarts{service="bar-1"}
restarts{service="bar-2"}
restarts{service="bar-3"}
```

I'm trying to use Alertmanager to trigger an alert when count of restarts of all instances of a service is more than a threshold.

The thing comes to my mind is to create a rule for each `foo` and `bar` separately using a query like this:

```
sum(restarts{service=~"bar-.*"}) > 10
```

But my services are too many to write a rule for each of them.

Is there any way to find restarts of each service in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `label_replace` in your query like:

`label_replace(restarts, "servicegroup", "$1", "service", "(.+)-.+")`

Then you can group the results with `sum by (servicegroup)` and get what you want.